# Pygame pixel array gives weird colors and freezes immidiately

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to scroll a world map horizontally using numpy.roll() on
a pixels2d object in pygame.

This is the picture I am using, but in .bmp: [image: image1]

This is what I get: [image: image2]

I tried changing the axis of np.roll(), but it didn't seem to affect the result much.

Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame as pg, numpy as np

pg.init()

world_map = pg.image.load('Miller.bmp')

screen = pg.display.set_mode(world_map.get_size())

world_map = pg.surfarray.pixels2d(world_map)


while 1:
    np.roll(world_map,1)
    screen.blit(pg.surfarray.make_surface(world_map), (0,0))
    pg.display.flip()
    pg.time.wait(1000)
```

Comment: It is freezing because you are not clearing the event queue.

`pygame.event.get()` or `pygame.event.pump()`

Do not use `pygame.time.wait` like this.

Comment: you can do it without `numpy` - use two `blit()` with correct `dest` and `area` in `blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags=0)` - see doc: [blit](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)

Comment: @BlakeO'Hare   Thank you. Now it doesn't freeze, but it still has the weird colors and it doesn't scroll. How **are** you supposed to control framerate in pygame?

Comment: @furas   That just makes is more complicated. You'd have to use incrementors and modulo, and it becomes much harder to understand.

Comment: No, it is very easy - I already made it

Comment: I disagree with it being much harder. Numpy is overkill. framerate is controlled with `pygame.clock`

Comment: and send on GitHub: [furas/python-examples/pygame/rolling-image](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/rolling-image)

Comment: @furas    Thank you, I adapted this method to my code. I made my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the adapted code with the help of this [repository from furas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/rolling-image):

```
import pygame as pg

clock = pg.time.Clock()

pg.init()

world_map = pg.image.load('Miller.bmp')
w, h = world_map.get_size()
screen = pg.display.set_mode(world_map.get_size())

FPS = 60
offset = 0
is_running = True
while is_running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            is_running = False
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                is_running = False

    offset += 1

    if offset >= w:
        offset = 0

    screen.blit(world_map, (0,0), (offset, 0, w, h))
    screen.blit(world_map, (w-offset,0), (0, 0, offset, h))

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pg.guit()
```

Comment: you need `while is_running:`, and `is_running = True` before `while` to exit `while` loop.  Now you will never exit program. And use `pygame.quit()` - sometimes window doesn't close if you don't use `pygame.quit()`.